# but has not been marked @Optional in testng.xml

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to run the below code using TestNG,

```
package Framework;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class XMLtestng {
    WebDriver d;




  @Test
  @Parameters({"fname"})
  public void reg(String fname) throws InterruptedException {
      d.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();
      d.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys(fname);
      d.findElement(By.name("register")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
  }

  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass() {
      d = new FirefoxDriver();
      d.manage().window().maximize();
      d.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
      d.close();
  }

}
```

And this is the corresponding xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">



  <test name="reg">
  <Parameter name="fname" value="Rachel"/>


    <classes>
      <class name="Framework.XMLtestng"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

when I run my xml file as TestNg suite,only the website's url is being opened and close. Actions to be performed (typing the firstname for registration), is not being executed. This is the message being printed in the console,

```
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Can anybody please help me in resolving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `P` is in caps for `Parameter` in `testng.xml`?

Comment: That was the syntax. When I tried with 'p', it showed in suggestion as 'P'(caps). Syntax cross check done in - https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/parameterization-in-testng

Comment: I don't understand what suggested you "P" but it was wrong. A good practice is to use the DTD to validate your suite file.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is skipped because you didn't provide it the expected parameter and it is not declared as `@Optionnal`.

The problem is you used `<Parameter...` instead of `<parameter...`.

Use the DTD to validate your file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
```